# JavaFX fireEvent StackOverflowError

Tags: java, events, javafx, javafx-2

I'm currently working on a little game with JavaFX, and i had some problems to catch keyEvents.

Now i can catch them but the program throw a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` and it didn't do what I expected when a key is pressed.

Here is the main class:

```
public class WarbladeFX extends Application {

    Game root;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = new Game();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        scene.setFill(new Color(0,0,0,1));


        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                Event.fireEvent(root, event);
            }
        });
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                Event.fireEvent(root, event);
            }
        });


        primaryStage.setTitle("WarbladeFX");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And the Game class:

```
public class Game extends Group {

    Entity ship;
    long delta;
    HashSet<String> input = new HashSet<>();

    public Game() {
        File f = new File("src/ressources/ship.gif");
        ship = new Entity(new Image("file:///" + f.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/")) ,300, 300);
        getChildren().add(ship);

        setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                //System.out.println(".handle()");
                String code = event.getCode().toString();

                if(!input.contains(code))
                    input.add(code);
            }
        });

        setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                String code = event.getCode().toString();
                input.remove(code);
            }
        });

        new AnimationTimer(){
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                if(input.contains("LEFT"))
                    ship.setVelX(-1);
                if(input.contains("RIGHT"))
                    ship.setVelX(1);

                ship.move(now);
                getChildren().clear();
                getChildren().add(ship);
            }
        }.start();
    } 
}
```

Some help would be very great.

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: Events fired on nodes in the scene graph will "bubble up" to the parent, and then the parent of the parent, and eventually all the way up to the scene. So the event handlers on the scene will "refire" the event to the `root`, which will then bubble up to the scene and get handled again, being refired to the root, and so on... What are you actually intending the event handlers on the scene to do?

Comment: I'm intending handle the events in my game class but without fireEvent it's just do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events fired on nodes in the scene graph will "bubble up" to the parent, and then the parent of the parent, and eventually all the way up to the scene. So the event handlers that you defined on the scene "refire" the event to the `root`, which will then bubble up to the scene and get handled again, being refired again to the `root`, and so on...

If you want to catch the events anywhere in the scene, and then handle them in the `Game` class, define some methods in `Game` to process the events and invoke those methods. Don't "refire" the events.

For example:

```
public class Game extends Group {

    Entity ship;
    long delta;
    HashSet<String> input = new HashSet<>();

    public Game() {
        File f = new File("src/ressources/ship.gif");
        ship = new Entity(new Image("file:///" + f.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/")) ,300, 300);
        getChildren().add(ship);



        new AnimationTimer(){
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                if(input.contains("LEFT"))
                    ship.setVelX(-1);
                if(input.contains("RIGHT"))
                    ship.setVelX(1);

                ship.move(now);
                getChildren().clear();
                getChildren().add(ship);
            }
        }.start();
    } 

    public void keyDown(String key) {
        if(!input.contains(key))
            input.add(key);    
    }

    public void keyUp(String key) {
        input.remove(code);
    }
}
```

and then you can do

```
public class WarbladeFX extends Application {

    Game root;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root = new Game();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        scene.setFill(new Color(0,0,0,1));


        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                game.keyDown(event.getCode().toString());
            }
        });
        scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                game.keyUp(event.getCode().toString());
            }
        });


        primaryStage.setTitle("WarbladeFX");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are generating an infinite loop when you fire the event again in the event-handle method. Try to handle the event in this method, i.e. react to the users input.

Comment: If I don't fire the event, it's like i don't have any event in my Game class

Comment: instead of refiring the event, call a method in your Game class that handles the event